# prove $ g(x) = x^{5} - x$ is surjective.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I know to be surjective , every real number in range maps to some real number in the domain of this function. Since isolating x in terms of y seems a bit tricky, I was thinking of using proof cases for specific values of y where the slope increases and decreases. I'm not sure, assuming this is the proper technique for this proof, how to rearrange x in terms of y?

edit: cannot use external facts/theories

Comment: Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @vadim123 pretty sure i'm not allowed to use external facts.

Comment: What are the *internal* facts, which you are allowed to use?

Comment: @vadim123 just the definition of surjective.

Comment: If you're not "allowed" to use Calculus, then how can you consider the derivative?

Comment: @GFauxPas yea I don't you can use calculus here, so I'm not sure how to approach this proof now only using the surjective definition. Maybe by contradiction, not sure.

Comment: You certainly need the mean value theorem to use calculus.

Answer (score 5):

You are far better off using the intermediate value theorem than trying to find a preimage for each real number. In general, this usually wont even be possible.

Let $r$ be a real number. Since $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}(x^5-x)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}(x^5-x)=-\infty$, there exists $N$ such that $g(-N)<-r$ and $g(N)>r$. Now $g$ is continuous on the interval $[-N,N]$, and since $r\in [g(-N),g(N)]$, there exists $s\in [-N,N]$ such that $g(s)=r$.

Comment: can't use external facts other than surjective definition.

Comment: What is the context here? It is not actually possible to solve $x^5-x=c$ in most cases, so you will definitely need to use some theorem other than just looking for preimages of points. The mean value theorem is equivalent to the completeness axiom, and usually proceeds any other results in analysis/calculus, so I sort of doubt it is off limits.